# Equivariant polynomial maps and gradients of invariants

Tags: finite-groups, invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with a linear action on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $f\in\mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ be invariant. Then the gradient of $f$ gives rise to a polynomial map $\phi$ from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$. This map is $G-$equivariant, i.e., $g(\phi(x))=\phi(g(x))$ for all $g\in G$. Now I wonder, if I get all $G-$equivariant maps from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$ in this way? (I think this is true for finite reflection groups, but also more generally?)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. The answer is 'no', essentially because there exist polynomial maps from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$ which are not gradients. So really, it is enough to cook up one such map, which in particular is $G$-equivariant too.

Consider $\mathbb{C}^2$, with coordinates $x_1$, $x_2$, and let $G = \{ \pm 1 \}$, acting on $\mathbb{C}^2$ by permuting the two coordinates $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Let $f(x_1,x_2) = (x_1^2 x_2, x_1x_2^2)$. Write $f = (f_1,f_2)$. The polynomial map $f: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ is $G$-equivariant. If $f$ is a gradient, then in particular, we must have the "integrability condition"

$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}$

but this is clearly not satisfied for all $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2$.